# Commutation of homotopy groups with filtered colimits

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, simplicial-stuff, model-categories, higher-algebra

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a model category with a forgetful functor towards simplicial sets, and such that fibrations and trivial cofibrations are those whose underlying map on simplicial sets is a fibration, respectively trivial fibration.
Is there a criterion to decide whether formation of simplicial homotopy groups commutes with filtered colimits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of any such criterion (and I'm doubtful a very general one exists, if any), so this is not meant to be an answer (but for some reason I'm unable to post it as a comment right now).

A few remarks.
The question is slightly ill posed. What do you mean by "**commutation** of simplicial homotopy groups with filtered colimits"?
You probably mean formation of simplicial homotopy groups turns, in degree zero, filtered colimits in $\mathcal{C}$ into filtered colimits of pointed sets, and in positive degree it turns filtered colimits in $\mathcal{C}$ into filtered colimits of groups.

It seems to me a **necessary** condition on $\mathcal{C}$ is that it is **proper** (see Goerss-Jardine, Ch. II, $\S$8).
Indeed, if formation of higher simplicial homotopy groups commutes with filtered colimits in the above sense, then in particular pushouts along cofibrations preserve weak equivalences.

In fact, a sharper necessary condition is that weak equivalences in $\mathcal{C}$ are closed under filtered colimits.
This should be seen as a strong "finiteness condition" on $\mathcal{C}$: it is typically met if generating cofibrations and generating trivial cofibrations are small relative to the whole category $\mathcal{C}$ (which is stronger than requiring $\mathcal{C}$ to be "finitely generated").

You may then ask whether it is the case that in a model category satisfying your stated assumptions, and in which, in addition, filtered colimits preserve weak equivalences, formation of higher simplicial homotopy groups commutes with filtered colimits in the above sense.

I don't have a counterexample off the top of my head, but I'm led to believe this is not the case in general.

Comment: Thanks! I found a counterexample thanks to these remarks. I'll type it up as time permits, and post it here.